# Can I get how many "likes" by a specific user using Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am developing an app that tracks the users day and id like to tell the user how many hours he/she spends on Instagram and how many pictures has he / she liked on her profile? Is this possible to get from the Instagram API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

This will return list of media liked by a user, you can keep track of media_id's and count how many liked every day, going forward.

Not sure how you plan to get data of how many hours spent on Instagram, there is no API